# How to change JBoss EAP server.log file permission

Tags: jboss-eap-6

Is there a configuration setting in Jboss EAP 6.3 (Domain mode) that can be done to change the permissions for the server.log file?

Currently it appears the default for server.log is 640.  I'd like to change it to 644 so there is global read access so that our patrol monitoring job can read server.log.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting to control this (although on may be useful).

The default permissions are controlled by the user's umask. If it being created with 640, that likely means the umask is set to 026 or 027, which disables access by other by default. If you set it to 022, all files created by JBoss will be readable by all users.